# Speed Up Twine Cipher for Java Card

Tags: java

I implemented the lightweight cipher Twine described 
[here](http://jpn.nec.com/rd/crl/code/research/image/twine_SAC_full_v4.pdf) but it seems to me that this is not sufficiently optimized.
For example, below I have the key expansion for 80 bits:

```
    private void expand80Key(byte[] key)
{

    short len_x = 20;
    short key_size = 10;
    short iterator = 0,iterator2=0;;
    byte temp_val=-1;
    byte temp_val2=-1,temp_val3=-1,temp_val4=-1;
    short sh=0;
    // reset the array
    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(temp, (short)0, (short)20, UNTOUCHED_VALUE);

    for (iterator = 0 ; iterator < key_size; iterator++)
    {
        //key[iterator] = (byte)(key[iterator] & 0xff);
        temp[(short)(2*iterator)] = (byte)((short) (key[iterator] & 0x00FF) >> 4);
        temp[(short)(2*iterator+1)] = (byte)((short) (key[iterator] & 0x00FF) & 0x0F);
    }

    for ( iterator = 0 ; iterator < 35;iterator ++)
    {
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 0)] = temp[1];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 1)] = temp[3];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 2)] = temp[4];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 3)] = temp[6];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 4)] = temp[13];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 5)] = temp[14];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 6)] = temp[15];
        rk[(short)(iterator * 8 + 7)] = temp[16];

        temp[1] ^= sbox[temp[0]];
        temp[4] ^= sbox[temp[16]];
        temp_val = roundconst[iterator];
        temp[7] ^= temp_val >> 3;
        temp[19] ^= temp_val & 7;

        temp_val = temp[0];
        temp_val2 = temp[1];
        temp_val3= temp[2];
        temp_val4 = temp[3];

        for (iterator2 = 0 ; iterator2 < 4;iterator2++)
        {
            sh = (short)(iterator2*4);
            temp[sh]   = temp[(short)(sh+4)];
            temp[(short)(sh+1)] = temp[(short)(sh+5)];
            temp[(short)(sh+2)] = temp[(short)(sh+6)];
            temp[(short)(sh+3)] = temp[(short)(sh+7)];
        }
        temp[16]   = temp_val2;
        temp[17]   = temp_val3;
        temp[18]   = temp_val4;
        temp[19]   = temp_val;
    }
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 0)] = temp[1];  
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 1)] = temp[3];  
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 2)] = temp[4];  
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 3)] = temp[6];  
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 4)] = temp[13]; 
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 5)] = temp[14]; 
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 6)] = temp[15]; 
    rk[(short)(35 * 8 + 7)] = temp[16]; 

}
```

I wanna know if there is a way to optimize this kind of loops. Also I don't know when to allocate the memory in RAM instead of EEPROM. Until now I allocated the memory this way:

```
public static byte[] temp   = new byte[MAX_MEMORY_TEMPORARY];  // TODO consider allocating tmp in RAM
public static byte[] rk     = new byte[36*8]; 
private static byte  [] roundconst = 
    {
            0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x23, 0x05, 0x0a, 0x14, 0x28, 0x13, 0x26,
            0x0f, 0x1e, 0x3c, 0x3b, 0x35, 0x29, 0x11, 0x22, 0x07, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0x38, 0x33, 0x25, 0x09, 0x12, 0x24, 0x0b,
    };
private static short [] shufinv = {1, 2, 11, 6, 3, 0, 9, 4, 7, 10, 13, 14, 5, 8, 15, 12};
private static short [] shuf = { 5, 0, 1, 4, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 6, 9, 2, 15, 10, 11, 14};
private static byte  [] sbox = {0x0C, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0A, 0x02, 0x0B, 0x09, 0x05, 0x08, 0x03, 0x0D, 0x07, 0x01, 0x0E, 0x06, 0x04};
```

Comment: Beside the off topic-ness, the Java Card API can be found on the internet. What's keeping you from looking up `makeTransientByteArray` yourself? Buy a book for starters, such as the venerable Java Card Technology for Smart Cards book. The principle ideas remain unchanged (unless you count the Connected Edition)